# How to setup a web api controller Post method

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am changing my project to post multiple objects  to my db table. The issue I am having is, after I changed the Post method I do not know how to return the created route with the Id's of the objects. I have not done this before so I believe I a correct on everything else up until that point.

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostNewPurchaseOrderDetail([FromBody]IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> newPurchaseOrderDetail)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                context.PurchaseOrderDetails.AddRange(newPurchaseOrderDetail);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return CreatedAtRoute("PurchaseOrderDetailApi", new { newPurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderDetailId }, newPurchaseOrderDetail);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Error Message

> Error 2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'PurchaseOrderDetailId' and no extension method 'PurchaseOrderDetailId' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Development\TexasExterior\TexasExterior\apiControllers\apiPurchaseOrderDetailController.cs   58  98  TexasExterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what the issue is. You variable, `newPurchaseOrderDetail` is an enumerable of `PurchaseOrderDetail`, and you're trying to reference a property of `PurchaseOrderDetail` directly off of it. You need to get a single item from the list before you can call the property. For example:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("PurchaseOrderDetailApi", new { newPurchaseOrderDetail.First().PurchaseOrderDetailId }, newPurchaseOrderDetail);
```

Notice the `.First()`. However, that would only give you the id of the first item in the collection, which is probably not what you want. I'm not sure what your `CreatedAtRoute` method does or how it works, but you could change the second parameter to expect a collection of ids and then pass something like:

```
newPurchaseOrderDetail.Select(m => m.PurchaseOrderDetailId)
```

Which would give you a list of ids.